# Array / fit curve modifier doesn't produce a long enough array to fit entire curve

Tags: modifiers

I've had loads of issues around getting objects to fit and follow the multiple curves in my project. I've searched and overcame every obstacle but one, that I'm aware of lol. I continue to have an issue with the array modifier, using fit curve, not fitting the entire length of certain curves. I have had this modifier work the first time on multiple occasions on brand new curves. However, the curves I'm specifically having this issue with were originally edges of a mesh selected with vertices, duplicated, separated, and converted to curves. Some of these problem curves were joined together as they visually create a continuous line.

As far as I can tell all scale values are 1 and apply scale has been used multiple times between all my problem curves and hasn't resolved the issue.

When using the fixed count fit type, I can push the array past this stopping point, but the array fails to follow the curve past that point. Specifically, the arrayed object just continues straight in one direction.

I literally opened Blender for the first time 5 days ago so this issue has to be a user error. I just haven't nailed down what I'm messing up and the old google machine hasn't produced a working solution. Happy to post my file, I just can figure out how...

[image: image showing the problem array object not fitting to curve. Curve selected, vertices visible.]

[image: image showing the problem array objects "N" panel info]

[image: shows one of my problem curves selected and displays the rough length of some of the curves]

[image: Image displays arrayed objects starting, endpoint, and intended endpoint]

Answer (score 1):

If you make a default cube, and a default circle, the default cube is 2 units wide and the default circle has a circumference of 2pi (2 * radius * pi).  How do you evenly array something 2 units wide into something 6.28... units longs?  You can't.  2 doesn't go into 2pi evenly.  So Blender makes 4 of the cubes.  (Differences in yours may be due to unapplied scale, but it doesn't matter; you're not going to get any array to fit any curve exactly.)

As for things failing to follow the curve after its end-- there is no curve after the end.  If you want it to continue to curve, create more curve.  Which you can do by entering edit on your curve, selecting a control, and 'e' to extrude it.

Now, you might find it useful to enable "stretch" and "bounds clamp" on your curves, in properties/object data/shape.  If you do this, any curve modifiers you use will stretch the modified mesh to fit the curve-- so those 4 cubes, 8 units long, 2 units each, will turn into 4 cubes, 6.28... units long, pi/2 units long each.

Comment: The curves are large and an exact fit is not necessary.

Comment: I've added another image showing the arrays starting point (arrow), where the array stops prematurely (red circle), and the endpoint I'm trying to get the array to reach (green circle)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to redraw the curves. It was easier and just simpler to use the problem curves as snapping points for a fresh bezier to be placed. For what it's worth, I appreciate the info.